# Aligning virtual address to immediate next page boundary

Tags: c, paging

I came across following algorithm that aligns virtual address to immediate next page bounday.

```
VirtualAddr = (VirtualAddr & ~(PageSize-1));
```

Also, given a length of bytes aligns length (rounds it) to be on the page boundary

```
len = ((PageSize-1)&len) ? ((len+PageSize) & ~(PageSize-1)):len;
```

I am finding it hard to decipher how this works.
Can someone help me out to break it down?

Comment: That aligns a virtual address to the immediate _previous_ page boundry

Comment: ...and the second one doesn't work at all, unless there's other assumptions you haven't mentioned.  (Oh wait, `if (len<=PageSize)` then it's `len`, otherwise it's len rounded up to the next page boundary.  That's quite different than what you described.

Comment: Yes you are correct.
1. For first statement to align to immediate next boundary should be((VirtualAddr+PageSize) & ~(PageSize-1))
2. And the second statement of the second line rounds to page size.

Comment: Your correction to the first problem is _also_ incorrect (ish), as it adds unneeded padding to those already aligned; use `((VirtualAddr+PageSize-1) & ~(PageSize-1))` instead.

Comment: ```lang-py
>>> hex(0x00053000 & ~(4095))
'0x53000'
>>> hex(0x00053FFF & ~(4095))
'0x53000'
>>> hex(0x00052FFF & ~(4095))
'0x52000'
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Those calculations assume that the page size is a *power of 2* (which is the case for
all systems that I know of), for example

```
PageSize = 4096 = 2^12 = 1000000000000 (binary)
```

Then (written as binary numbers)

```
PageSize-1    = 00...00111111111111
~(PageSize-1) = 11...11000000000000
```

which means that

```
(VirtualAddr & ~(PageSize-1))
```

is `VirtualAddr` with the lower 12 bits set to zero or, in other words,
`VirtualAddr` rounded *down* to the next multiple of `2^12 = PageSize`.

Now you can (hopefully) see that in

```
len = ((PageSize-1)&len) ? ((len+PageSize) & ~(PageSize-1)):len;
```

the first expression

```
 ((PageSize-1)&len)
```

is zero exactly if `len` is a multiple of `PageSize`. In that case, `len` is left
unchanged. Otherwise `(len + PageSize)` is rounded down to the next multiple of
`PageSize`.

So in any case, `len` is rounded *up* to the next multiple of `PageSize`.

Comment: Selecting this answer. Detailed, descriptive and exactly what I was looking for.
Thanks everyone for helping me out :).

Answer (score 3):

I think the first one should be

```
VirtualAddr = (VirtualAddr & ~(PageSize-1)) + PageSize;
```

Comment: Actually, even this is not quite correct. This works unless VirtualAddr is already aligned. In this case, it will be advanced to the next page boundary.

Comment: You are right, maybe an if statement could check this.

Comment: this should do it I believe. ((VirtualAddr+PageSize) & ~(PageSize-1))

Answer (score 0):

This one-liner will do it - if it is already aligned aligned it will *not* skip to the next page boundary:

`aligned = ((unsigned long) a & (getpagesize()-1)) ?  (void *) (((unsigned long) a+getpagesize()) & ~(getpagesize()-1)) : a;`

This one-liner will do it - if it is already aligned aligned it will *not* skip to the next page boundary:

if you really *do* want to skip to the next page boundary even if it's already aligned - just do:

`aligned = (void *) (((unsigned long) a+getpagesize()) & ~(getpagesize()-1))`

This should avoid all compiler warnings, too.

`getpagesize()` is a POSIX thing. `#include <unistd.h>` to avoid warnings.